# Looping with number series

Tags: bash

I have made a loop in a bash script

```
for kr in {0..9} ; do
```

I want to also get `kr` to include the number `20`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work:

```
for kr in {0..9} 20 ; do
```